# Loop for in range of initializer_list

Tags: c++, object, initializer-list

```
Library::Library(std::initializer_list<Book> list) 
    : size{ list.size() }
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for (Book b : list)
    {
       insertBook(actual, b);
       actual = next(actual);
       size++;
    }
}
```

And errors:

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const Book' to 'Book'

and:

> Cannot copy construct class 'Book' due to ambiguous copy constructors or no
>   available copy constructor

My book.h constructors

```
Book();
Book& operator=(Book& old);
Book& operator=(Book&& old);
Book(std::string& author, std::string& title) :author(author), title(title)
{
    std::cout << "l-Referencja" << std::endl;
}
Book(std::string&& author, std::string&& title) :author(author), title(title) 
{
    std::cout << "r-Referencja" << std::endl;
}
Book(Book& old);
Book(Book&& old);
```

Comment: Post compilable code.

Comment: `Book& operator=(const Book& old)` and `Book(const Book& old);`.

Comment: Your title is misleading.  There is no loop in the *initializer list*.  There is a loop in the *constructor*.  The initializer list is: `: size { list.size() }`

Comment: You have a **really** weird copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator of an `std::initializer_list<T>` is `const T*`, so the range-based loop produces values of `const T`, or in your case, `const Book`.

Your class `Book` is however *not* constructible from constant values, since both its copy and its move constructor require mutable values.

You either cannot use an initializer list to communicate a list of `Book`s, or you need to redesign your class so that it can be constructed from a constant value.